# Why "with" statement is so slow?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, with-statement

this is my code, my question is why this code is so fast compared to the code that use the "with" statement?

```
var i = 0, Something = {};

for(i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    Something.Stupid = i;
}

// time = 0.026s
```

They do the same thing, no?

```
var i = 0, Something = {};

for(i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    with(Something) {

        Stupid = i;

    }
}

// time = 2.240s
```

Comment: Why are you still using `with` after all??

Comment: Now you know why everyone says "Do not use with" and it is not allowed in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Simplifying_variable_uses).

Comment: You should use strict mode. `with` is not allowed there, for good reasons.